# Animation is not working properly?

Tags: java, android, animation

I want to translate an imagebutton to another position(position to another imagebutton) via translate animation. I have both of their positions. The animation methods I have are all uses relative position changes, but I am interested in Absolute translation. Is there any method to do that in Android?

```
 public void startAnimationFindChant(View view) {
            int[] locationSource = new int[2];
            int[] locationDestination = new int[2];
            view.geLocationOnScreen(locationSource);
             Log.d("locationSource",locationSource[0]+" "+locationSource[1]);
            ImageButton findachant1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.findachanticon1);

            findachant1.getLocationOnScreen(locationDestination);
            Log.d("locationDestination",locationDestination[0]+" "+locationDestination[1]);

            TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, locationSource[1], Animation.ABSOLUTE,
                    locationDestination[1]);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            view.startAnimation(animation);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void doSlideUp(View view) {
    LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_area);
    Animation slideUp = setLayoutAnim_slideup();
    myView.startAnimation(slideUp);

}

public void doSlideDown(View view) {
    RelativeLayout myView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_area1);
    Animation slideDown = setLayoutAnim_slidedown();
    myView.startAnimation(slideDown);
}

public Animation setLayoutAnim_slidedown() {

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    set.addAnimation(animation);

    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
            set, 0.25f);

    return animation;
}

public Animation setLayoutAnim_slideup() {

    AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1.0f);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {




        }
    });
    set.addAnimation(animation);
    LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(
            set, 0.25f);
    return animation;
}
```

Try this and change the value of animation x asix to y axis as you required.

Comment: I guess the OP asked about absolute translation between two positions.

Comment: Yes I want Absolute Translation between two positions. Help me.

Comment: @Suleman Ilyas. You should change the position of float value from x axis to y axis. And give me detail what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I have made one simple class for TranslateAnimation between two position using ObjectAnimator -

```
private void translateAnimateView(View source, View target,
        AnimatorListener listener) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(source,
            "translationY", 0, target.getTop() - source.getTop());
    animator.addListener(listener);

    animator.setDuration(1000);
    animator.start();
}
```

This method accepts threee argument, source view, target view and listener(can be null). The source will be animated to reach target view. I have added just Y translation, but you can actually include x translation too.

This way you can have translation using absolute positions. You can anyways use the top coordinate instead of view though.